# Is Active Record in rails a driver?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, database-connection

I understood that we interact with DB using Active Record.
My question is, if Active Record in rails is a driver?

Answer (score 2):

No it isnt. [ActiveRecord](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/) is simply an library that adds ORM functionality to your data. It provides you with objects that encapsulate a row in the database table and adds business logic to it. AR also provides you some other excellent ways to smartly handle your data and it relationship, mostly keeping you agnostic from the nitty-gritty details of the different databases out there.

The drivers that are used for the db connectivity are not provided by AR and they are specific to the database that you use. There are some libraries that are specifically included for connecting to different databases like the mysql2 driver for connecting to MySQL, similarly for the other databases.

Answer (score 0):

In short, ActiveRecord isn't only driver. Drivers are gems mysql, pg, sqlite... ActiveRecors is thing like ORM for abstract database driver. [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)